# WPF DataGrid DataBinding is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my current WPF Application which I would like to bind to a ViewModel that holds a ObservableCollection. The user can enter search values in some TextBoxes and after enter has been hit I am performing an query to our database that retunrs a table of records. From these records I am populate the data for the ObservableCollection. I am now struggeling now that the datagrid is not displaying the data.

I have read a howl bunch of posts about the binding but I am still missing something I think.

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product : InotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";

    //public Product()
    //{

    //}
    private ProductViewModel _productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
    public ProductViewModel productViewModel { get { return _productViewModel; } set { _productViewModel = value; } }

    public DataTable ProductsTable { get; set; }

    public void GetProducts(string filter)
    {
        //< --doing some stuff to fill the table-->

        foreach (DataRow row in ProductsTable.Rows)
        {
            productViewModel.Products.Add(new Product
            {

                Title = (string)row["TITLE"],

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Product _SelectedProduct;
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get { return _Products; } set { _Products = value; } }

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**ProductWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="ProductsGrid" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"  
    CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Margin="10,10,10,10" 
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ProductWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class ProductWindow : Page
{
    public object DialogResult { get; private set; }
    //public ProductViewModel ProductViewModel;
    public ProductWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ProductViewModel();//stackflow
        //var ProductViewModel = products.ProductViewModel;
        //ProductsGrid.DataContext = new ProductViewModel();

    }

    public ProductViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as ProductViewModel;

    private void OnKeydownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var tb = sender as TextBox;
            Product products = new Product();
            string filter = "";//performing some ifelse to create filter
            products.GetProducts(filter);
            //ProductsGrid.DataContext = products.ProductsTable;
            //ProductsGrid.DataContext = products.productViewModel;

        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            ProductsGrid.DataContext = null;
            foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this))
            {
                // do something with tb here
                tb.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: fix the `set { _Products = value; }` add `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));`

Comment: @CelsoLívero still nothing. The collection is full of Items but they are not displaying. I have changed it to: public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get { return _Products; } set { _Products = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Products)); } }

Comment: take a look [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19Zs9Pl-xhpbfcmAATrX_DqM2fk3pXzVE), maybe this might help you

Comment: [here another help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675372/5605739), how can you do to use WPF in MVVM without any Toolkit

Comment: @CelsoLívero Very easily, if you bother learning how to use WPF at all.

Comment: Checked the links. It is for me way more confusing now. Because I have thought I have understand the basic but it seems I am absolutly not understanding the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DataContext` is a `ProductViewModel`, and the `Products` collection of that `ProductViewModel` is populated, you will see rows in your `DataGrid`. I've tested that. It appears that the viewmodel you're giving it may not have any rows.

That said, there's a problem with your design:

`Product` creates a `ProductViewModel`. `ProductViewModel` creates a collection of `Product`. Each `Product`, as I just said, creates a `ProductViewModel`. Which creates a collection of `Product`. They keep creating each other until you get a `StackOverflowException`. If you're not seeing that, you must be calling GetProducts() from somewhere else.

But there's no need for `Product` to own a copy of `ProductViewModel`. That's like adding a car to each wheel on your car.

So let's do this instead: `ProductViewModel` owns a collection of `Product`. Just that. And we'll call `GetProducts()` to make sure we get some items in the grid. Your binding is fine. You just weren't populating the collection.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ProductViewModel();
    }

    //  Now you can call ViewModel.GetProducts(filterString) from an event handler. 
    //  It would be more "correct" to use a Command, but let's take one step at a time. 
    public ProductViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as ProductViewModel;
}
```

Viewmodels

```
//  You didn't include any implementation of IEditableObject. I presume 
//  you can add that back in to this version of the class. 
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    //  You weren't raising PropertyChanged here, or anywhere at all. 
    //  In every setter on a viewmodel, you need to do that. 
    private string _title = "";
    public string Title {
        get => _title;
        set
        {
            if (_title != value)
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
            }
        }
    }

    public Product()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        GetProducts("");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Product _SelectedProduct;

    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return _SelectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedProduct)
            {
                _SelectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedProduct));
            }
        }
    }


    public DataTable ProductsTable { get; set; }

    public void GetProducts(string filter)
    {
        //< --doing some stuff to fill the table-->

        Products.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow row in ProductsTable.Rows)
        {
            Products.Add(new Product
            {
                Title = (string)row["TITLE"],
            });
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    //  This setter MUST raise PropertyChanged. See the Title property above for example. 
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get { return _Products; } private set { _Products = value; } }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### Update

Here's the problem: You create a new `Product`, which creates its own `ProductsViewModel`. *Nothing is bound to any property of that viewmodel*. You fill its collection and the DataGrid doesn't know or care, because you bound its ItemsSource to a property of a different object.

So use my suggestions above, particularly the `ViewModel` property of the window. **I just made a change in ProductsViewModel.GetProducts()** that you need to copy: Now it calls `Products.Clear()` before populating the collection.

```
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;

        //  Don't create this
        //Product products = new Product();

        string filter = "";//performing some ifelse to create filter
        ViewModel.GetProducts(filter);

    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        //  Setting the DataContext to null breaks everything. Never do that. 
        //ProductsGrid.DataContext = null;

        //  Instead, just clear the collection. It's an ObservableCollection so it will 
        //  notify the DataGrid that it was cleared. 
        ViewModel.Products.Clear();

        foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this))
        {
            // do something with tb here
            tb.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah sorry I missed a part. The GetProducts() is called and the collection is filled with in my case 137 different objects. If I set the DataGrid to AutoGenerateColumns="True" and perform in my OnKeydownHandler(where also getProducts() is performed) in ProductWindow.xaml.cs ProductsGrid.DataContext = products.productViewModel; the Datagrid is populating the collection. But I want to switch to AutoGenerateColumns="False" and adding the columns in xaml and there are the datagrid is not populating the rows.   For now I will try to follow your answer and try to get things work

Comment: I was writing an identical response (well, almost) to what Ed Plunkett wrote, if you make the changes that he made will work, there was really a problem when using the GetProducts method, among other problems in your code, Ed Plunkett explained them in detail...

Comment: @josef_skywalker Please show the actual real complete code for the version that “is not populating the rows”. Don’t leave out any important parts. I need to be able to reproduce what you’re seeing on your screen. You should in any case make the changes I suggest.

Comment: @josef_skywalker Are you creating a new Product in the event handler?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am listening if the user hits enter and if it is true i perform products.GetProducts(filter);

Comment: @josef_skywalker Show me the code. I need to see the code. Paste it into your question, don't put it in a comment. If you don't show me the code I asked for, I will go away and nobody will help you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have added the code. Hope this will clear things up.

Comment: @josef_skywalker It does, thank you. You are creating a new `Product` and populating its viewmodel. But that's not bound to the DataGrid. You just create a new collection and throw it away. See my update.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Wow, thanks this actually helped me to get things fixed. Also I have now understand the pattern better. Thanks for your well explained solution.

Comment: @josef_skywalker My pleasure. Glad we got it nailed down.